# How to convert row into column in PostgreSQL of below table

Tags: postgresql, join, pivot

I was trying to convert the trace table to resulted table in postgress. I have hug data in the table.

I have table with name : Trace

```
entity_id                         | ts                | key         | bool_v  |   dbl_v |   str_v   | long_v  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593934026155   | temperature   |         |         |           | 45      |
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593934026155   | operation     |         |         |   Normal  |         |
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593934026155   | period        |         |         |           | 6968    |
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593933202984   | temperature   |         |         |           | 44      |
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593933202984   | operation     |         |         |   Reverse |         |
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593933202984   | period        |         |         |           | 3535    |
```

[Trace Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxlit.png)

convert the above table into following table in PostgreSQL

Output Table: Result

```
entity_id                         | ts            | temperature | operation | period    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593934026155 | 45          | Normal    | 6968      |
1ea815c48c5ac30bca403a1010b09f1   | 1593933202984 | 44          | Reverse   | 3535      |
```

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNvOq.png)

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: I tried but not able make it because of multiple parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this yet?

```
select entity_id, ts,
       max(long_v) filter (where key = 'temperature') as temperature,
       max(str_v) filter (where key = 'operation') as operation,
       max(long_v) filter (where key = 'period') as period
  from trace
 group by entity_id, ts;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes i tried this but there is performance issue. I have billions of data so i want the optimized query to process the data faster.

Comment: @PavankumarBehere Is your table indexed, or does it have a primary key?  I cannot think of a faster way to do this pivot unless there are many `key` values other than `temperature`, `operation`, and `period`.  Even so, with as much data as you have, building an index would take a very long time and consume a lot of space.  If `ts` is critical to your analysis, have you considered looking into a solution like https://www.timescale.com/ ?