# How to pivot a table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, case-when

Here's the thing, I have this table:

```
id    rank    price
1     1       100
1     2       200
2     1       300
2     2       100
2     3       200
3     1       300
```

And I want to build something like this:

```
id    price_rank_1    price_rank_2    price_rank_3
1     100             200             NULL
2     300             100             200
3     300             NULL            NULL
```

This should be pretty simple, just some sort of case when, Idk, but I can't figure it out.

Update: I tried the answer from [How to convert row into column in PostgreSQL of below table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751478/how-to-convert-row-into-column-in-postgresql-of-below-table/62753974#62753974):

```
select id,
       price filter (where rank=1) as price_rank_1,
       price filter (where rank=2) as price_rank_2,
       price filter (where rank=3) as price_rank_3,
from table
```

But I got the error:

```
Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "("
```

Comment: Please see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62753974/13808319

Comment: @MikeOrganek many thanks, I think the problem was that I didn't know exactly what to search. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Yes, please.  If not, somebody will likely flag it a duplicate and close it on you.

Comment: @MikeOrganek weird thing, the answer from the post is not working. I will update my question so you or anyone else can see

Comment: What is your Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` expression has to be on an aggregation function:

```
select id, 
       max(price) filter (where rank = 1) as price_rank_1,
       max(price) filter (where rank = 2) as price_rank_2,
       max(price) filter (where rank = 3) as price_rank_3
  from your_table 
 group by id;
```